# Why can't I remap the laptop fn key modifier?

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes

I've remapped the laptop key fn to Hyper using:

```
(setq ns-function-modifier 'hyper)
```

to scroll other window I set

```
(global-set-key (kbd "H-n") 'scroll-other-window)
(global-set-key (kbd "H-p" ) 'scroll-other-window-down)
```

H-n works but H-p inserts a * char instead of scrolling down.

M-x scroll-other-window-down works fine, only the mapping does not.

Comment: The fn-key is problematic in this regard as it is able to generate keysyms on a lower level, such as on the p key when numpad is enabled. Check whether such a thing is on for you.

Comment: In some laptops the fn key will send an actual * keycode (when combined with the appropriate key). That happens way above Emacs, so if that's the case for you then you might be out of luck.

Comment: The Fn key is usually interpreted vendor specifically at the BIOS level --- it doesn't get to the OS, doesn't produce a KeySym, doesn't get interpreted by any application. It's not a good idea to rely on the Fn key for anything other than its intended purpose, and even then not really.

Comment: I need AltGr remapped to  control, and FN remapped to AltGr (mac-like keyboard), because the FN is in the wrong place between right control and alt gr, but there is no way to remap it.